# Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process', Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2'

Tags: node.js, file-upload, next.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to create a web-page using nodeJS and nextJS that stores documents on google drive. For this I installed the NPM module "googleapis" but when I import this module in my particular JS file it throws an error as mentioned below,

```
./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:17:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js
```

To solve this error I have tried the below solution and this method resolved my issue, I have added this below solution in `next.config.js`

```
webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        fs: false,
        path: false,
        child_process: false,
      }
    }
    return config
  },
```

This solution solved my issue but throws another error as mentioned below,

```
./node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/http2.js:16:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2'
Did you mean './http2'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js
./node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js
```

This http2 module is deprecated by NPM.

**How to resolve this http2 module issue or does anyone know that how to tackle this child_process issue?**

Comment: `googleapis` and `google-auth-library` are Node.js client, they can't be used on the client-side. When using Next.js, they can only be used inside `getServerSideProps`/`getStaticProps` or in API routes.